# Is there any way to keep a memory block for a container?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, set

I hope I'll be clear....

In my code, I define a `box` which holds a set of elements (`bead`):

```
vector<vector<vector<set<std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> > > > > boxes;
```

I am adding element to the `box` using:

```
boxes[i][j][k].insert(aBead);
```

For some reason I get a segmentation fault here. As far as I can tell, The segmentation fault does not occur because of illegal `bead` and `i`, `j`, `k`, are all smaller than the box's size and are not negative.

In case you wonder bead is:

```
class particle{
  public:
    vec pos;
    vec oldPos;
    vec vel;
    vec F;
    vec oldF;
    int charge;
    int type;
    double U;
    double nextU;
};

class bead: public particle{
  public: //most of this is redundant...
    int charge;
    int type;
    double rho;
    double nextRho;
    int LID;
    bool keep;
    bool touch;
    double radius;
}

class vec{
  public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    velarray<double> coor; //on it's way to being canceled
}
```

Comment: `vector<vector<vector<set<std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> > > > > boxes;` ... Wow, just wow.

Comment: Do you have a better ID for efficient way to keep track of 3D possitions of thoughsands of particles?

Comment: `particle` seems to have. `pos` and `oldPos` already. What I can't think of is any reason why a 4 dimensional container is needed to track a single particle in 3 dimensional space.

Comment: How about `std::map<std::tuple<int,int,int>, std::set<...>>`?

Comment: particle follow himself. I devide the system into smaller areas (boxes) and I keep note of which paticle is inside each box. This is so beacouse the particle interactions calculation is expencive

Comment: @Kerrek SB: With map, I think, I can't have a sufficient way to itereate over boxes (more importantly, arround close boxes). I considered this solution at first but it felt too slugish to me (no actual measurement though).

Comment: Perhaps a 3-dimensional kd tree would be a suitable structure if you need neaerest-neighbour type searches...

Comment: Seems like you need a new object to define what a `box` is first.

Answer (score 4):

When creating a `shared_ptr<T>`, you will want to intiailize it with a pointer to the object type that has been created using the `new` keyword, not with an actual object or object reference.  For instance:

```
shared_ptr<bead> ptr(new bead);
```

not

```
bead aBead;
shared_ptr<bead>(aBead);
```

BTW, also **do not** do the following:

```
bead* ptr = new bead();
shared_ptr<bead> sptr(ptr);
delete ptr;
```

The `shared_ptr<bead>` object manages the lifetime of the pointer.  It will reference count the pointer, and call `delete` on the pointer internally in the `shared_ptr<T>` destructor when there are no more references to the pointer.  If you manually call `delete` on the pointer after initializing the `shared_ptr<T>` object, you will end up with a segmentation fault as well, since you've basically tried to self-manage the memory life-time, defeating the whole pointer of a managed "smart" pointer like `shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: Before I do anything, when I delete the pointer, and this is not the only pointer pointing to that object. What will happen to the other pointer?

Comment: Don't call delete on the pointer! ... the life of the pointer will be managed by the shared_ptr object ... it now "owns" the pointer.

Comment: the smart pointer deletes it for you when the last reference falls out of scope. If you use `std::shared_ptr` you shouldn't be calling delete at all.

Comment: The only way that a `shared_ptr` would not delete the memory it's managing would be if you created some type of cycle in the pointer graph.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work afterall. I think it did but it only transfered the problem down the code (same command, same error)

Comment: Have you actually reserved the space for each sub-vector component of your `boxes` data-structure?  In other words `boxes` has to be initialized with a `vector<vector<set<std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> > > >` data-type, which in-turn is initialized with a `vector<set<std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> > >` data-type.  You will have to "build-up" the `boxes` data-structure with repeated calls that have reserved enough space in each vector for the actual `i`, `j`, and `k` indexes.  Is that the way your code is structured?

Answer (score 2):

If you have support for C++11, then the preferred way to make a dynamic object plus shared pointer is `make_shared`:

```
boxes[i][j][k].insert(std::make_shared<Bead>());
```

Failing that, you will have to perform the dynamic allocation yourself, but thenceforth the lifetime of the object will be managed by the shared pointer:

```
boxes[i][j][k].insert(new Bead);
```

You might like to change your data structure, though, to avoid excessive use of containers. Each container incurs allocations, which may turn out to be expensive. If you need to fill 3D space densely, then you could use a flattened-out 1D view that you access in strides. If you only need sparse points, a map keyed on triples may be an option.

Comment: I have no idea if I support that or not. Thanks though.

Comment: OK. I'll have to check this after all. After I have used the make share, how do I access the bead?

Comment: Exactly as before. `make_shared` creates a shared pointer, along with the object instance itself. It's a more efficient substitute for `shared_ptr<Bead>(new Bead)`.

Comment: Yeah but how do I assign anything to that pointer. It doesn't have to be the last pointer in the set...